# GWT Module com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet not found

Tags: java, maven, gwt, vaadin

I have converted my existing project from vaadin 7 to vaadin 8 successfully. There is no error in the project, but when I use `mvn install` to build the project. I am getting this error:- **GWT Module com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet not found in project sources or resources.**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:51 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-19T12:31:15+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 94M/1007M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:8.0.6:compile (default) on project XXX: GWT Module com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet not found in project sources or resources. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Please attach pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

From [here:](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/15031831)

**Check the following:**

You have to replace the `vaadin-server` dependency with `vaadin-compatibility-server`.

**If you are using the default widgetset** (you are not compiling it by yourself):

Replace the `vaadin-client-compiled` dependency with `vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled`.

Add `@Widgetset("com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet")` to your UI implementations.

**If you are using a custom widgetset:**

Replace the `vaadin-client` dependency with `vaadin-compatibility-client`.

Recompile it.

In your POM I see these lines:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.10</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

This won't work, you can't include any version 7 components, servers, clients.
The only valid thing, is to use the v8-compatibility things.

Comment: I included all the compatibility dependencies in the pom but I also keep the existing dependencies with their versions and exclude that dependencies from new compatibility dependency.
Is this approach causing the existing issue?

Comment: Show your pom.xml file

Comment: Here is the [POM.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1awCNsdiz0DoBZc2qV67ZkYXOSUUCgJ4j/view?usp=sharing) file

Comment: Remove all vaadin.xxxx version 7.x dependencies in your pom.xml

Comment: This is a pretty huge project and if I remove 7.x dependencies it will affect multiple files. So I can't afford to remove those dependencies. Is there any way that, I can keep 7.x dependencies with 8.x and remove the occurred error.

Comment: It's pretty simple to solve. Just replace all your imports of the corresponding UI elements and data elements to the compatibility package. com.vaadin.ui.TextField becomes com.vaadin.v7.ui.TextField. There is eve a maven task doing this for you. https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8.html There will be some minimal things to fix after this, but it should at least compile and run